# Java code cannot find resource file after build and clean in Netbeans IDE?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, file-io

I really need your help to solve my own problem. Now, I'm dealing with small code app. In that project folder contain some resource files (*.xlsx, *.png,...). I placed them in current folder with code file. I just wonder that when I run my code in netbean ide, it just worked find.

After I build code project, I get a jar file in "dist" directory. I run it. It open normally since app used JFrame as user interface. However, when I execute some function of that app, it showed me the error log. Here is the error message:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
src\sample.xlsx (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

What's the matter out there?

Here is some pieces of my code:

```
copyFile(new File("src\\sample.xlsx"),
new File(txtout.getText()+"\\sample.xlsx"));
```

*Node:* copyFile function is used for copy file from source to dest.

Here is my project folder structure in Netbean IDE:

1. Project Name

   - Source Pakage(src)

     - myClass.java, sample.xlsx, etc

Comment: Hopefully, this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230), be able to help somewhat on the topic :-)

Answer (score 3):

First, never reference `src` directly, the directory will not exist once the program is built.  Second, you can not access resources which have been embedded within in the application context via a `File` reference, they simply no longer exist on the file system.

Instead, you need to use `Class#getResource` or `Class#getResourceAsStream`

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/sample.xlsx");
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/sample.xlsx");
// Don't forget to manage your streams appropriately...
```

Comment: Thanks. Let's me try that.

Comment: Excuse me!! It still stay the same. By the way, As I opened jar file in WinRAR, I saw that sample.xlsx is in there as well. The question is can I reference that file?

Comment: `sample.xlsx` is no longer a file, it a compressed series of bytes managed by a zip entry.  Does the above example return a result or do they return `null` (or an exception)?

Comment: As I printed the url out, I saw that it get the absolute file. but it get it does not work. By the way, my folder name has blank space. Is it can be the matter?

Comment: And the second method, java did not reorganized the `getResourceAs` function.

Comment: Should be `getResourceAsStream` sorry.  If the `getResource` method returned a non-`null` value, it will print out something like `jar:file:/C:/DevWork/personal/java/projects//JavaApplication260/dist/JavaApplication260.jar!/sample.xlsx` - You can not assume where this resource might reside (Netbeans will use the `classes` directory, but when run from the Jar, it will use Jar entry).  You CAN NOT reference the resource as a `File`, it simply can not be done with the file embedded within your application. If you want to, move it outside of the `src` and use a relative path instead ;)

Comment: Hi. Just for a clarification related to [this Meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234266/187824). Which vote did you cast in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24299064/1369235)?

Comment: @hims056 Wow, okay, I think I went for "why does this code not work" option

Answer (score 2):

Well you can create a folder named `resources` under the `src` folder put your resources in it and  use them in your code by using  `getResourceAsStream()` and `getResource()` methods that can access the embedded resources.`Clean and Build` will compile the code and embed the contents of the resources folder into the application’s .jar file.
**Ways of Accessing resources :**

```
    String pathToImage = "resources/images/filling.png";
    InputStream stream= ClassName.class.getResourceAsStream(pathToImage );

   String pathToImage = "resources/images/filling.png";
   InputStream stream= ClassName.class.getResource(pathToImage );
```

please refer the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845231/how-to-correctly-get-image-from-resources-folder-in-netbeans) information